# Elasticsearch similarity match score for set of terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to query for similarity (match score) for set of terms in elasticsearch?

**Simple example**:

Data:

```
doc1:{
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]
 }
 doc2:{
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2", "tag4"]
 }
```

Query:

```
criteria:{
    "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
 }
```

Result

```
Result:{
    doc1 - match 100%
    doc2 - match 66.6%
 }
```

Explanation:
doc1 has all tags that are present in search
doc2 has 2 of 3 tags that are present in search

So basically query that will return list of documents ordered by match, where match = how similar are tags in document compared to tags in query. No fuzziness needed. Return in % is just an example, return in points or some other unit is fine. Number of tags can be different.
I am designing system so can store data in any format, whatever works for ElasticSearch. I looked at their docs, but probably missed this type of search.

Many thanks for help.

**Improvements**

Is it possible to specify custom weight of match for each tag? 
I.e. tag1 - 100points (or 20%), tag2 - 200 points (or 40%).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the [similarity module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-similarity.html)

Not sure about weighted match, maybe the boost attribute?

Comment: Thats a useful feature, but how it will help me with finding tag score? I guess that's per field. And my field is basically array of elements.